# MySQL cannot enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE on server

Tags: mysql

First I am a novice MySQL user so I would please ask that in answers to keep it very by the numbers if steps are skipped I will probably get lost.

I have tried vigorously to research solutions before asking this, so far I have spent about 3 hours on this. I will explain what steps I have taken to the best of my abilities.

Goal: Allow the use of the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Challenge:  Currently the command is not allowed on the server.  All attempts to locate and open some method to modify server options has proved fruitless.  On the client side I was able to enable it.

Things I have found
First under the official Tutorial I found
Section 6.1.6, “Security Issues with LOAD DATA LOCAL”
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html

Unfortunately the explanation is worthless because it skips a huge amount of how to, they state to enable it on the server to take the following action

On the server side:

The local_infile system variable controls server-side LOCAL capability. Depending on the local_infile setting, the server refuses or permits local data loading by clients that have LOCAL enabled on the client side. By default, local_infile is disabled.

To explicitly cause the server to refuse or permit LOAD DATA LOCAL statements (regardless of how client programs and libraries are configured at build time or runtime), start mysqld with local_infile disabled or enabled, respectively. local_infile can also be set at runtime.

So the following actions are not in any way explained

1) How to start mysqld with local_infile disabled or enabled
2) How the local_infile can also be set at runtime

So then I looked at this

5.1.1 Configuring the Server
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-configuration.html

Again many skipped steps they show this

shell> mysqld --verbose --help

How do you get to shell?  I tried on cmd to input that but I got errors

Also to note a my.ini was not created, and under the MySQL Workbench when looking under Options File it says

"Location of My SQL configuration file (ie: my.cnf) not specified"

It appears I do not have one and I have no idea how to create one

Finally I am running Windows 10 and MySQL version 8.0

As a side note I tried shutting down the server and got and Access denied

Also I tried just doing

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet;
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Whew 4 hours later and I finally figured it out!

So here are the steps

1. Open Window Services
2. Go to MySQL80 and double click
3. Go to Service Status and click Stop
4. Under Start parameters insert --local-infile=1
5. Open MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client
6. After you login excute on the command line SET GLOBAL local_infile ='ON;

These steps allowed me to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Comment: can you explain this step 4 please?

Comment: @FarahNazifa: right click on the service in the "services" window, click "properties". Under the "General" tab, i in the bottom, you have a "Start parameters" text field.

Comment: This is the only working soluiton I found. Thank you